# javaでfor文の中のcontinueの数をひとつにしたい

Tags: java, java8

javaでfor文の中のcontinueの数をひとつにしたいです
sonarqubeを用いて解析しているのですが、continueの数をひとつにしてくださいというエラーが出るのですが対応方法がわかりません
下記のような実装になっているのですがご教授いただけると幸いです

```
for(line:List){

 if(isAAA(line)){
   実行文;
   continue;
 }
 if(isBBB(line)){
   実行文;
   continue;
 }
 if(isCCC(line)){
   実行文;
   continue;
 }
 if(isDDD(line)){
   実行文;
   continue;
 }

}
```

追記
また実行文がないパターンについても教えていただきたいです

```
for(line:List){

 if(isAAA(line)){
   continue;
 }
 if(isBBB(line)){
   continue;
 }
 if(isCCC(line)){
   continue;
 }
 if(isDDD(line)){
   continue;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

この形であれば if ... else if ... を使ってください。continue は必要ありません。

if の中身が continue だけなのであれば、そのようになる条件たちを or でまとめてひとつの if にすれば良いです。

Comment: ありがとうございます！解決しました

Comment: 良かったです。回答の横のチェックマークを押すと回答を承認できますのでしていただけると私が嬉しいです :)